# Checking the validation of a field through the Property mutator method `set`

Tags: c#, properties

I'm newish to C#, being mainly Java oriented. I have a field `_config` which needs to be a value from 1 to 8, and I have this code which checks to make sure I can only set `_config` to 1-8. If the value given for set is "invalid", `_config` becomes -1.

```
public int Config {
    get
    {
        return _config;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value > 8 || value < 1)
        {
            _config = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            _config = value;
        }
    }
}
private int _config; // the actual field that the property 'Config' refers to.
```

This feels really weird to me, but it does what I need it to do. I'm also thinking about having the setter throw an exception instead of setting `_config` to -1 when given an invalid value. Am I using Properties correctly, or have I completely misunderstood the point of them?

Comment: I would just suggest using a `Range[2,7]` attribute for this property. Validate an entire model at once instead of individually for each property. If an "invalid" value is allowed, make it `null` instead of `-1`, which other may find confusing.

Comment: I looked for a couple of examples on using `[Range]` but I still don't fully understand it. Say I set the range attribute like so: `[Range(1, 8, ErrorMessage = "Helpful error message.")]` What happens when I set an invalid value? Do I get the error message to console or elsewhere? Does this stop the code from continuing to execute? Can I somehow customize this error message portion?

Comment: The validation attributes don't really *do* anything by themselves - they serve as metadata. There are different ways to validate the model itself. For example, if receiving this model as a parameter for an API endpoint, you can create an actionFilter that does something like `actionContext.ModelState.IsValid`. This is a built-in property that validates the entire model and generates a response with any/all appropriate error messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No one has yet addressed the fact that you have chosen the wrong tool for the job.

What does `Config` represent? It looks like you should have chosen an `enum` where you chose an `int`.

```
public enum ConfigurationType
{
    None = 0,
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    // etc.
}
```

You can get what `ConfigurationType` an `int` corresponds to quite easily:

```
ConfigurationType configType = (ConfigurationType)someInteger;
```

Then, you can validate it more fluidly:

```
public ConfigurationType Config
{
    get
    {
        return _config;
    }
    set
    {
        if (ConfigurationType.IsDefined(typeof(ConfigurationType), value))
        {
            _config = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException($"The specified value must be a valid value of the {nameof(ConfigurationType)} enumeration.");
        }
    }
}
private ConfigurationType _config; // the actual field that the property 'Config' refers to.
```

If you don't have C#6.0, your exception would be more along the lines of:

```
throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(string.Format("The specified value must be a valid value of the {0} enumeration.", ConfigurationType.ToString()));
```

---

You should also consider a refactoring of the name `Config`, it's non-descriptive. There is likely a better name for such a property/field combination. (Had we more context we would likely be able to suggest better names.)

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. int is not the best type I could use here, solely because it can handle so many values. The enumeration provides a simple solution for what I want to do with the code, and becomes extensible for future development. I also see dcastro's solution of throwing an exception for invalid arguments in this solution, which I now believe is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @endrnc The enumeration can hold *just as many* values as an `int` as well. In .NET, `enum` types are basically `int` (or a different type, if you specify it) in disguise.

Comment: It's true that the `enum` *can* hold just as many types, but at runtime it can only reference as many as you have explicitly stated before compiling. This is essentially behavior I'm looking for. Unless there's some method to adding items to an enumeration that I haven't heard of before (which I would love to read/learn about if there is!)

Answer (score 3):

The setter of the property Config has more than one responsibility, instead of just setting the value, it's also validating it and even changing it's value. The purpose of writing the code is not just that it does what you need to - there will very likely be other users (programmers) of your code. Most of them will expect that setter of the property will simply set its value, and not doing lots of other stuff, but the most dangerous point is changing its state. Separate validation from the setter and use other ways to express invalidity of the property's value.

Comment: I see how it brings about unexpected behavior, which I guess is what crawled under my skin in the first place. How would you recommend I separate the validation from the setting? I'd like to not check the validation everywhere I use this value, and instead check once when I set the value.

Comment: Hmm, having only 6 possible values makes me think "int" is not the most suitable type for the property, could be even "primitive obsession smell" (serch on Google for this subject). On the other hand, int might be the suitable type but in this case are you really sure that the valid Config property's value could be only 2-7 for all "consumers"? If you are not sure what future modification requests might bring, it'd better idea to separate concerns regarding data and validation - in the real world it's usually someone other's responsibility to validate values.

Comment: Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127290/c-sharp-add-validation-on-a-setter-method

Answer (score 3):

In a sense, your usage of properties is *somewhat* incorrect.

From the book Effective C# by Bill Wagner:

> Properties are methods that can be viewed from the calling code like data. That puts some expectations into your users’ heads. They will see a property access as though it was a data access. After all, that’s what it looks like.

I would consider setting the value to something else other than the input value an unexpected result. In other words, it violates the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment):

```
obj.Config = 10;
Assert.Equal(10, obj.Config); // <-- fails
```

The *usual* behaviour is to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: The quote says "get accessors", you're talking about a setter.

Comment: @BenAaronson That's a good point. I'll update my answer

Comment: In other words, throwing an exception from the setter where it's currently setting `_config` to -1 right? What's the downside to doing this during a `set` operation if any?

Comment: @endrnc That's correct. I don't know of any downside - I see that approach all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do that. This is very confusing for the consumers of the class.

You have two options.

1. Throw exception when setting to invalid value.
2. Automatically use valid value when consumer has set an invalid value. You can optionally log a message somewhere indicating the value system used.

```cs
public int Config { get; set; }

private int FinalConfig { get { return Config > 8 || Config < 1 ? -1 : Config; }
```

In your code, you use `FinalConfig` everywhere. You can optionally make it public so that consumer can find out which value was used by your code.